# OpenStack python API create server with block_device_mapping_v2

Tags: python, openstack-nova

I was able to create server using block_device_mapping parameter but it fails when I use block_device_mapping_v2:

```
block_device_mapping_v2 = {'vda':'57854259-d6db-4efd-b87c-0767473d2cc6:snap::1'}
instance = nova_client.servers.create(
image='',
name='test_server',
flavor=flavor,
block_device_mapping_v2 = block_device_mapping_v2
```

)

```
novaclient.exceptions.ClientException: The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation. (HTTP 500) (Request-ID: req-d0ed01c1-226c-447a-b1d8-cf17b4257e7c)
```

How to properly make block device mapping for v2?